# pl/sql negative look behind regex

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to implement a regular expression in pl/sql which excludes any results which are preceeded by a string.

```
data:

exclude this: 3
include this: 3
3
cvxcvxcv3
34edfgdsfg3

Using this regexp:
(?<!exclude this: )3\d{0}(\s|$)

What I would expect to be returned is:
exclude this: 3   <-- nothing
include this: 3   <- 3
3                 <- 3
cvxcvxcv3         <- 3
34edfgdsfg3       <- the second 3 only
34edfgdsfg33      <- the last 3 only
```

This works fine when tested in notepad++ however when implementing it in pl/sql it isn't working. Looking at similar questions it appears that pl/sql doesn't support negative lookback fully but does anyone know of a similar construct or a way to work around this?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the logic? Reverse engineering your notepad++ code is not possible.

Comment: Currently I have a regex that works, however when looking at the output, I have found that the current expression isn't sufficient as it returns results I want to filter out further. So for example if I currently have 3\d{0}(\s|$) as my regexp. What will be returned will be verything I want in addition to the rogue result (which in this case would be the entry for 'exclude this: 3'). It is this additional filtering which I require.

Comment: May be my question is not clear. Explain how you want to see the output and logic behind that? So you need to explain in plain english about the logic behind the regex

Comment: In plain English this regex looks for the number 3 as long as it isn't followed by anything else. What I want is something that also says 'give me all of the number 3's which aren't followed by anything except for the cases where the number 3 is preceeded by "exclude this: " - ommit those results also'  edit: When the regexp is constructed in my example it does work in notepad++, however pl/sql doesn't support regexp in the same way - it is this which I am looking for an answer to

Answer (score 0):

While i am not aware of any general technique to emulate negative lookbehind by means of pl/sql regexen, in your particular case a solution is possible:

```
([^e].{13}|[^x].{12}|[^c].{11}|[^l].{10}|[^u].{9}|[^d].{8}|[^e].{7}|[^ ].{6}|[^t].{5}|[^h].{4}|[^i].{3}|[^s].{2}|[^:].|[^ ]|^)3[^0-9]?(\s|$)
```

The negative lookbehind applies to a literal. Therefore all forbidden prefixes of the first character that must match are known beforehand as are their lengths. this allows for a compact (well ...) specification as a regex that must match.

Not that I would recommend that for best practice ... or any practice at all ...

**Update** (processing advice):

The regex as it stands identifies matches without providing any further information for postprocessing. However, you can identify the offset of the match and the length of the forbidden prefix with the following code:

```
DECLARE
    s_data      VARCHAR2(4000); -- This will contain the line you match against
    s_matchpos  BINARY_INTEGER; -- Offset of the 'interesting' part (digit '3' under the various constraints) in s_data
    s_prefix    VARCHAR2(100);  -- The prefix part of the match
    s_re        VARCHAR2(4000); -- The regex
BEGIN
    s_re := '([^e].{13}|[^x].{12}|[^c].{11}|[^l].{10}|[^u].{9}|[^d].{8}|[^e].{7}|[^ ].{6}|[^t].{5}|[^h].{4}|[^i].{3}|[^s].{2}|[^:].|[^ ]|^)3[^0-9]?(\s|$)';
    s_prefix    := regexp_replace( s_data, s_re, '\1', 1, 1);   -- start at offset 1 of the data and find the first match
    s_matchpos  := regexp_instr( s_data, s_re ) + length(s_prefix);
END;
```

As mentioned above, not necessarily to recommend as best practice ...

Comment: Hi, I thought this was working but it turns out it doesn't. What it seems to do is do the select and also any preceeding chars as (up to 14). I only want to select the '3' and nothing else still. <exclude this string>(Reg exp).